# Rails: Possible to have a hidden scope always active?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I am creating some models in order to pull data more easily from a database I do not control. I have a model `Dataset`. I only care about entries where `Dataset.where(type: 'set')`.

I know that I could make a scope to do this.

```
class Dataset < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :set, ->{ where(type: 'set') }
end
```

I'm wondering if it's possible to have the scope always applied. Meaning I could call `Dataset.all` and actually get the entries where type is 'set'.
Is it possible to have a scope always active and hidden like this?

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for [*default_scope*](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v4.2/active_record_querying.html#applying-a-default-scope).

> If we wish for a scope to be applied across all queries to the model
>   we can use the default_scope method within the model itself

```
class Dataset < ActiveRecord::Base
  default_scope { where(type: 'set') }
end
```